# Ubuntu not instaling

Tags: system-installation, mount, wubi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.1-desktop-i386 on a 32-bit Thinkpad T400 with Windows 7 on it. I have tried installing Ubuntu by mounting the ISO from a DVD+R I burned, a USB drive, and my downloads folder. I mount the ISO with Virtual Clone Drive. I downloaded the ISO from the Ubuntu website. When I try to install by rebooting the computer, I get sent straight to Windows 7, as if a regular restart just occurred. When choosing the "Help me boot from CD" option, I am asked to install CD boot helper. Unfortunately, an error comes up that says:

Cannot install into C:/ubuntu. 
There is another file or directory with this name. 
Please remove it before continuing.

For more information, please see the log file: 
c:/users/admin/appdata/local/temp/wubi-14.04-rev286.log

I am not sure what to do. I deleted the wubi-related files I could identify in the folder, and it still does not work. Please help.

EDIT: I want to remove Windows 7 from my computer, and Ubuntu is not installed at all on my computer. Just in case I wasn't clear

Answer (score 0):

You should run a [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) via a live CD/DVD or USB drive. That should fix up your GRUB bootloader so that you can choose between Ubuntu and Windows 7.

Comment: Does not work...

Comment: If you want to remove Windows 7 and just have Ubuntu, why don't you just install Ubuntu from a disc or USB and have it erase everything?

Answer (score 0):

first fix the bootloader  using the steps in below URL

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair